# Реализация ввода текста в новом окне (Toplevel), но я не могу получить эти данные

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Я хотел получить данные с нового окна, а после обработки, вывести их в консоль.

```
def P():
windowP = Toplevel()
mass = Entry(windowP).pack()
Volume = Entry(windowP).pack()
btnP2 = Button(text = 'find P', command = P2)
btnP2.pack()
def P2():
mass3 = mass.get()
Volume3 = Volume.get()
print('Ok.' + mass3/Volume3)
```

Однако компилятор говорит что mass и Volume не используется, хотя я хочу получить из них данные в mass3 и Volume3. При попытке использовать программу, выводиться - "Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\еае\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 53, in P

```
mass3 = mass.get()
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
"

Я пытался найти информацию в интернете, но нашел сравнительно мало данных насчет Entry в Toplevel, я уверен что моя ошибка связано с тем что mass локальная переменная, но при попытке дать ей глобальность, через global, кнопка "find P" (btnP2) появилась в основном окне, но не в windowP, а также я получил ту же ошибку

"mass3 = mass.get()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'"

Comment: Поправьте отступы в коде.

Comment: Ошибка связана с тем, что в строке `mass = Entry(windowP).pack()` в переменную записывается не объект Entry, а результат вызова метода pack() - а т.к. он ничего не возвращает, то записывается None. Поэтому не нужно совмещать создание объекта и запись в переменную с его размещением.